# Log in link not showing, Comment Issue

Tags: comments, login, genesis-theme-framework

We want user to register and then comment. So we,

- Checked the option of "Anyone can register" as true.
- Checked the option of "Users must be registered and logged in to comment" as true.

Now, the problem is nothing shows up in a single post page below "Speak your Mind". Here is the snapshot of problem ->

[image]

Here is the comment.php of the parent file.

```
    <?php
/*
 WARNING: This file is part of the core Genesis framework. DO NOT edit
 this file under any circumstances. Please do all modifications
 in the form of a child theme.
 */

/**
 * Handles the comment structure.
 *
 * This file is a core Genesis file and should not be edited.
 *
 * @category Genesis
 * @package  Templates
 * @author   StudioPress
 * @license  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GPL v2.0 (or later)
 * @link     http://www.studiopress.com/themes/genesis
 */

if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) && 'comments.php' == basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) )
    die ( 'Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!' );

if ( post_password_required() ) {
    printf( '<p class="alert">%s</p>', __( 'This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.', 'genesis' ) );
    return;
}

do_action( 'genesis_before_comments' );
do_action( 'genesis_comments' );
do_action( 'genesis_after_comments' );

do_action( 'genesis_before_pings' );
do_action( 'genesis_pings' );
do_action( 'genesis_after_pings' );

do_action( 'genesis_before_comment_form' );
do_action( 'genesis_comment_form' );
do_action( 'genesis_after_comment_form' );
```

Comment: That is entirely determined by the theme. Find your theme's `comments.php` and post the contents.

Comment: I work n genesis so don't actually have any comments.php. Its the News Child Theme.

Comment: Well, it is controlled by your theme nonetheless. You will need to find where.

Comment: Something is probably hooked to `genesis_comment_form`. Find that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did the old school way of disabling all plugins and enabling them one by one as suggested by the Studiopress Support team  and found out that 'Genesis Simple Comments' plugin was causing this problem.

Nick, the author of the plugin said that it needs an update, so for now the issue is solved.